# Using Matplotlib to add text along with a plot in a pdf file

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way of drawing a caption box in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777576/is-there-a-way-of-drawing-a-caption-box-in-matplotlib)

I am trying to add a text description of a graph that I draw with matplotlib.  I was wondering if there was a way to add a small description that is not in the frame of the graph (ie. either below it or above it).

I saw this link [add text to existing pdf using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180115/add-text-to-existing-pdf-using-python), but I would like to use matplotlib to do so.  If there is no way to do this outright, is there another way (such as creating another figure, but instead of plotting coordinates, writing text in the area)?

I also noticed there is `figtext(x, y, s, fontdict=None, **kwargs)`,  but this adds text at certain coordinates.

Comment: Could you explain what you need beyond `title` can do?

Comment: I already use title, I need something like a text box, where I can say these were the conditions which the tests were run under

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jim, if I understand your question correctly, you're looking for a text area to use as a caption or description below a figure in matplotlib.

If so, you may find your answer through this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777576/is-there-a-way-of-drawing-a-caption-box-in-matplotlib).