# Styling part of label in legend in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, customization, legend

Is it possible to have **part** of the text of a legend in a particular style, let's say, **bold** or *italic*?

Comment: Have you tried whether tex-formatting works for the legend?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As silvado mentions in his comment, you can use LaTeX rendering for more flexible control of the text rendering. See here for more information: http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html

An example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

# activate latex text rendering
rc('text', usetex=True)

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
z = np.random.random(10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, label = r"This is \textbf{line 1}")
ax.plot(x, z, label = r"This is \textit{line 2}")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note the 'r' before the strings of the labels. Because of this the \ will be treated as a latex command and not interpreted as python would do (so you can type `\textbf` instead of `\\textbf`).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! In case it helps someone else, I had trouble to run the example code in Ubuntu 11.10 until I installed the `texlive` (I had `texlive-base`) and `texlive-latex-extra` packages.

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04, I needed `texlive`, `texlive-latex-extra`, and `dvipng` to get this example working.

Comment: On the latest version of *Ubuntu 19.10* one would also need `cm-super`; So the whole list of packages now needed is gonna be the following, in a single installation command: **`sudo apt-get install dvipng texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended  cm-super`**

Comment: I can't get a text to in sans serif font (such as Helvetica) with italics. I have tried used `\mathregular` but nothing changes.

Answer (score 60):

Write between `$$` to force matplotlib to interpret it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10), range(10), label = "Normal text $\it{Italics}$")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is indeed much easier than the accepted answer and does not require latex to be installed. For bold text use `\bf` instead of `\it`.

Comment: @homayoun the \it works fine, but the \bf does not. I sthere a link to the documentation where? what other \handles are there?

Comment: Here is some documentation for the `$...$` syntax: https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html

Comment: @dmeu for bold it should be \\bf (double slashes)

Comment: Doesn't work for sentences: Spaces between words disappear, since this feature is meant for math, not text. You'll have to bold/italic each word separately.

Comment: You can do something like this to retain the spaces: `'Normal text' + ' '.join(['$\it{'+i+'}$' for i in my_label.split(' ')])`, where `my_label` is the label you want to make italic

Comment: use `\ ` (backslash space) to insert a space in mathmode.  $these\ are\ words$.  `$\mathrm{whatever}$` is also useful to know about.

Comment: Nice answer, though I was applying this in to the title keyword in a matplotlib legend and I had to use an r-string to get it to work, i.e. `plt.legend(title=r"Normal text $\it{Italics}$")`.

Comment: Nice answer indeed! How about color? Bold and italic were just examples.

Answer (score 6):

Adding more options to the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40362346/2956066) by fixing the issues with that answer, with **OO** interface not just the state-based pyplot interface, possibility to have spaces as part of the text, **boldface** option in addition to *italics*:

```
ax.legend(handles=legend_handles,
          labels=legend_labels,
          loc='upper right',
          shadow=True,
          fancybox=True,
          facecolor='#C19A6B',
          title="$\\bf{BOLDFACED\ TITLE}$",     # to boldface title with space in between
          prop={'size': 12, 'style': 'italic'}  # properties for legend text
         )
```

For *italicized* title with space in between replace the above `title` with,

```
 title="$\\it{ITALICIZED\ TITLE}$",
```