# How to make the legend text and box bold?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

On pyplot -  I can't figure out (pun not intended) how to make the text and the box of the legend **bold** (well, the text bold and the linewidth of the box wider). That's what I have so far.

```
import pylab as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
...
ax.bar(...)
...
ax.legend(loc='best',prop={'size':35})
```

Comment: You can insert tex/latex, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376335/styling-part-of-label-in-legend-in-matplotlib

Comment: Thanks Scott, I ended up using FontProperties from here (it has size and weight) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot

Comment: Now you know how to do it two ways :)

Answer (score 0):

The [legend demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/legend_demo.html) in the matplotlib gallery subtly shows both of these -- note that the original reset the font size and got access to the frame Rectangle (to change the color). Add one next-to-last line:

```
legend.get_frame().set_linewidth(3.0)
```

and the rectangle frame is heavier:

[image]