# Make part of a title bold and a different color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to change part of a title to be bold. For example:

```
plt.title("This is title number: " + str(number))
```

Given a title like the above, how would I bold the `str(number)` part.

Comment: Seems like people have given response to making part of the title as bold. What about making part of the title colored?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## activate latex text rendering

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)

plt.title("This is title number: " + r"\textbf{" + str(number) + "}")
```

Comment: How do I both underline and bolden the text: r"\textbf\underline does not seem to work?

Comment: @Caledonian26 \textbf{ \underline{text}}

Comment: How do set a color to a text in title?

Answer (score 90):

From matplotlib version 2 on, 
there is no need to use latex (which would require a working latex installation).   One can use normal MathText to render part of the title in bold.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
number = 2017
plt.title("This is title number: " + r"$\bf{" + str(number) + "}$")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The disadvantage of this: It seems to works for a number or 1 word. But if the string is "hello world", the space gets lost -> "helloworld".

Comment: @Alpha A space in mathmode is achieved with a slash `\\`. See e.g. [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375709/space-in-math-mode).

Comment: I like this way of setting the font. How do we  set color using this?

Comment: Amazing! I always called latex from python but always came across with plenty of bugs

Answer (score 0):

This post should answer your question on manipulating the title. You can use latex text rendering and call textbf for that particular part of the string.

[Styling part of label in legend in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376335/styling-part-of-label-in-legend-in-matplotlib)

Here is the documentation:
http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html
http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title

Comment: External links can change, hence it is preferred to copy the interesting section of an external page in your comment. Copying the interesting section of an external page and citing where it's from is best!