# Matplotlib change font size for only part of a title

Tags: python, matplotlib

This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937048/make-part-of-a-matplotlib-title-bold-and-a-different-color) shows how to make part of a figure title or axis label bold. How do you change the font size of part of a title?

```
ax.set_xlabel('Unadjusted Font Size' + '\n' + r"$\bf{" + 'How do I make this part FontSize100?' + "}$")
```

Using Python 3.8

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use:

```py
plt.figtext(.5,.9,'Text 1', fontsize=100, ha='center')
plt.figtext(.5,.8,'Text 2',fontsize=30,ha='center')
```

You can read more about it here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figtext.html