# Italicizing letters and numbers in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am attempting to italicize text in my plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,1,1], label = '$\it{ABC123}$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

as shown by [Styling part of label in legend in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376335/styling-part-of-label-in-legend-in-matplotlib)

but this only italicized `ABC`, not `123`, which was also noticed, but left unsolved, by [Matplotlib italic font cannot be applied to numbers in the legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69964702/matplotlib-italic-font-cannot-be-applied-to-numbers-in-the-legend?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have also tried `usetex` [italic symbols in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470137/italic-symbols-in-matplotlib) but that *changes the fonts* which make this figure incompatible with other figures that I'm making.

I'm on Python 3.10.12 and

```
matplotlib                3.8.1
matplotlib-inline         0.1.3
```

how can I italicize both letters and numbers, e.g. in `ABC123`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the font_manager:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

font = font_manager.FontProperties(style='italic')

plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,1,1], label = 'ABC123')
plt.legend(prop=font)
plt.show()
```

[image]

To use it for x/y ticks or labels, you must use the fontproperties argument:

```
plt.yticks(fontproperties=font)
```

Comment: great! will this work for yticklabels as well?

Comment: Yes, see my added example at the bottom of my answer.