# Adding Caption to Graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, caption

I have a conceptual problem in the basic structure of matplotlib. 
I want to add a Caption to a graph and I do understand the advice given in [Is there a way of drawing a caption box in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777576/is-there-a-way-of-drawing-a-caption-box-in-matplotlib) 
However, I do not know, how to combine this with the pandas data frame I have.
Without the structure given in the link above my code looks (projects1 being my pandas data frame):

```
ax2=projects1.T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
ax2.set_xlabel('Year',size=20)
```

and it returns a barplot.
But if I want to apply the structure of above, I get stuck. I tried:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig.add_axes((.1,.4,.8,.5))
ax2.plot.bar(projects1.T,stacked=True)
```

And it results in various errors.
So the question is, how do I apply the structure of the link given above with pandas data frame and with more complex graphs than a mere line.  Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas [plot function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) has an optional argument `ax` which can be used to supply an externally created matplotlib axes instance to the pandas plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

projects1 = ...?

fig = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig.add_axes((.1,.4,.8,.5))

projects1.T.plot.bar(stacked=True, ax = ax2)
ax2.set_xlabel('Year',size=20)
```