# Plotting a horizontal bar graph in matplolib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following data frame:

```
    strterminationreason    total_trials    %Trials
0   Completed, Negative outcome/primary endpoint(s...   3130    6.390624
1   Completed, Outcome indeterminate    3488    7.121565
2   Completed, Outcome unknown  6483    13.236555
3   Completed, Positive outcome/primary endpoint(s...   15036   30.699498
4   Terminated, Business decision - Drug strategy ...   526 1.073952
5   Terminated, Business decision - Other   1340    2.735922
6   Terminated, Business decision - Pipeline repri...   1891    3.860917
7   Terminated, Early positive outcome  231 0.471640
8   Terminated, Lack of efficacy    1621    3.309649
9   Terminated, Lack of funding 533 1.088244
10  Terminated, Other   1253    2.558291
11  Terminated, Planned but never initiated 4441    9.067336
12  Terminated, Poor enrollment 3201    6.535587
13  Terminated, Safety/adverse effects  993 2.027441
14  Terminated, Unknown 4811    9.82277
```

I used the following code to plot a bar graph , horizontally since normal one doesn't fit the text codes above.

```
df['%Trials']=(df.ix[:,1]/sum(df.ix[:,1]))*100

plt.figure(figsize=(35,20))
plt.barh(df.ix[:,2],df.index,align='edge')
plt.xlim([0,31])
plt.yticks(df.index, df.strterminationreason)
plt.ylabel("TerminationReason",fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel("%Trials",fontsize=20)
```

But I get the output where the range of the bars doesn't reflect the actual % value in the dataframe. Like the highest % is for Completed, Positive outcome/primary endpoint but it doesn't show the same. Any idea why?

[image]

Also do someone know how to correctly fit the text under each bar so that there is no overlapping and is clean.

Comment: Please check the sequence of arguments to [`barh`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.barh):   `matplotlib.pyplot.barh(bottom, width, height=0.8, left=None, hold=None, **kwargs)` -- `bottom` is y-coordinate of your bars, `width` is width of bars on the x-axis

Comment: Didn't understand. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your plot appears incorrect is that you're passing arguments to `barh` in reversed sequence. You can find the documentation for `matplotlib.pyplot.barh` [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.barh). Here's a slightly modified script that resolves your problem:

```
bottom = range(len(df.index))
width = df['%Trials']
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.barh(bottom, width,color='r',align='edge')
ax.set_yticks(y_pos)
ax.set_yticklabels(df.index)

plt.show()
```

Regarding fitting your long labels, you may want to tweak the font, padding or wrap the lines for readability. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740682/wrapping-long-y-labels-in-matplotlib-tight-layout-using-setp) and [here](http://worksofscience.net/matplotlib/tick_labels).