# split tick labels or wrap tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have pretty long plot tick labels which unfortunately I cannot shorten. I am thus looking for a code to split the label into multiple lines (wrap text). I tried text wrap but it caused an error in my code. 
Having the tick label at `rotation=0` makes the tick label overlap each other and becomes un-readable.

I also tried having a `rotation=90` but the tick label instead spills into my chart space.

```
plt.title(param)
plt.ylabel('Measurement')
plt.xticks(x_axis, labels, rotation = 10, fontsize=8, horizontalalignment="center")
plt.tick_params(axis='x', pad=6) 
lgd = ax.legend(loc = 'upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
```

Comment: i tried that. but it did not work. the code just will not execute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`textwrap` is the way to go. More precise the function `textwrap.fill()`. You haven't posted the error message you got, but I do assume you passed the whole array `labels` to `fill()` which will cause an error message. Use list comprehension instead to pass each individual label to `fill()` and it will work.

```
x_axis=range(5)
labels = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'] * len(x_axis)

plt.title('param')
plt.ylabel('Measurement')
# Note list comprehension in the next line
plt.xticks(x_axis, [textwrap.fill(label, 10) for label in labels], 
           rotation = 10, fontsize=8, horizontalalignment="center")
plt.tight_layout()           # makes space on the figure canvas for the labels
plt.tick_params(axis='x', pad=6)
```

gives

[image]

Comment: First, you have to `import textwrap` before to use this code.