# How to extend the space for y ticks in barh - python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Please see attached image

[image]

I have the source code as follows in python

```
def plotBarChartH(self,data):
           LogManager.logDebug('Executing Plotter.plotBarChartH')

           if type(data) is not dict:
               LogManager.logError('Input data parameter is not in right format. Need a dict')
               return False

           testNames = []
           testTimes = []

           for val in data:
                testNames.append(val)
                testTimes.append(data[val])

           matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8})     
           yPos = np.arange(len(testNames))
           plt.barh(yPos, testTimes, height=0.4, align='center', alpha=0.4)
           plt.yticks(yPos, testNames)
           plt.xlabel('time (seconds)')
           plt.title('Test Execution Times')
           savePath = os.path.join(ConfigurationManager.applicationConfig['robotreportspath'],'bar.jpg')
           plt.savefig(savePath)
           plt.clf()
           return True
```

The bar looks fine but I have two issues

1. How can the text in y-axis can be shown in full? I mean some text are cut-off and i want to extend the space in occupies so that it can be displayed in full.
2. Can I Increase the whole plot area on which the charts are drawn? I want to increase the width of of plot area so that image looks bit bigger

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How can the text in y-axis can be shown in full? I mean some text are cut-off and i want to extend the space in occupies so that it can be displayed in full.

You could use `plt.axes` to control where the axes are plotted so you can leave more space in the left area. An example could be `plt.axes([0.2,0.1,0.9,0.9])`.

2. Can I Increase the whole plot area on which the charts are drawn? I want to increase the width of of plot area so that image looks bit bigger

I do not understand what you mean.

- You can control the size of the figure using `plt.figure` (e.g., `plt.figure(figsize = (6,12))`)
- You can control the space between the information and the axis using `plt.[xy]lim`. For example, if you want more blank space in the right area you could use `plt.xlim(200, 600)`.
- You can save some margin space using `plt.axes` (See question 1 above).

Comment: Hi, what does the array represent [0.2,0.1,0.9,0.9]? I am playing around with the values but not able understand what they actually represents.

Comment: It indicates normalized values for xmin, ymin, xmax and ymax. So if you use 0,0,1,1 there is no margin, if you use 0.1,0.1,0.9,0.9 you left 10% on each side between the axis and the figure border,...

Answer (score 5):

You can set the figure size (in inches) explicitly when you create a `Figure` object with `plt.figure(figsize=(width,height)), and call`plt.tight_layout()` to make room for your tick labels as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

names = ['Content Channels','Kittens for Xbox Platform','Tigers for PS Platform',
         'Content Series', 'Wombats for Mobile Platform']

values = [260, 255, 420, 300, 270]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
yvals = range(len(names))
ax.barh(yvals, values, align='center', alpha=0.4)
plt.yticks(yvals,names)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What is that lovely palette you are using?

Comment: @mel I think it’s just the (old) default Matplotlib blue with some alpha.

Answer (score 2):

1. One option is to include newline characters `\n` in your string (or use something like `"\n".join(wrap(longstring,60)` as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351565/how-do-i-fit-long-title) answer). 
   You can adjust you plot area with `fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.3)` to ensure the whole string is shown,

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

val = 1000*np.random.rand(5)    # the bar lengths
pos = np.arange(5)+.5    # the bar centers on the y axis
name = ['name','really long name here', 
        'name 2', 
        'test', 
        'another really long \n name here too']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.barh(pos, val, align='center')
plt.yticks(pos, name)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.3)
plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]

2. You can adjust the physical figure size with `figsize` argument to subplots or figure.

Example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(12,8))
```

the amount of space in the figure can be adjusted by setting axis based on the data,

```
ax.set_xlim((0,800))
```

or automated with `ax.set_xlim((0,data.max()+200))`.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2020: simply calling `.autoscale` on plt should work:

You can do that right before `plt.show()`

```
plt.autoscale()
```

OR

```
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y', tight=None)
```