# matplotlib place axes within figure box

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my code (I am running it in a jupyter notebook on OS X )

```
% matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_facecolor('gray')
ax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
print fig.get_figwidth()
```

I was expecting to see a large gray figure box with a small white axes box in the bottom left hand corner. What I get is a small white axes box with a small gray box surrounding it.

I am obviously missing some setting or other. How do I get what I was expecting?

[image: What I see]

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimentation and digging I found the answer in the [matplotlib magic](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-matplotlib) documentation referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864735/matplotlib-and-ipython-notebook-displaying-exactly-the-figure-that-will-be-save?rq=1).

The ipython magics are enforcing bbox_inches='tight' by default. which causes the figure bbox to shrink to fit the axes.

The trick is to add the magic line

`% config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None}`