# matpliblib - Add title to pie chart center with legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to add a title to pie chart with legend at right. Currently, the title not at the center!

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def plot(df,xname,yname,pngname):
    title = "sample title"
    x = df[xname]
    y = df[yname]
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
    patches, texts = ax.pie(x,#autopct='%.1f%%',
                            startangle=90, radius=1.2,
        wedgeprops={'linewidth': .1, 'edgecolor': 'white'},
        textprops={'size': 'x-large'})

    labels = ['{1:1.1f} {0}'.format(i,j) for i,j in zip(y,x)]
    patches, labels, dummy=zip(*sorted(zip(patches, labels, x),
                                          key=lambda x: x[2],
                                          reverse=True))
    plt.legend(patches, labels,
               frameon=False,
               loc='center left',
               bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5),
               labelspacing=0,
               #handletextpad=0.1,
           fontsize=12)

    ax.set_title(title)
    plt.tight_layout()
    fig.savefig(pngname, dpi=fig.dpi, bbox_inches="tight")
    print("[[./%s]]"%pngname)
    return

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'key':  ['AAAA', 'BBBB', 'CCCC', 'DDDD'],
    'value':[ 20  ,6,   6,   8]})

plot(df,"value","key","demo.png")
```

How can I put the title at the center?

[image]

Comment: One quick thing - in the future, please don't include "`savefig`" statements or the like in your MWEs, unless that's the focus of your question. In general, include as little code as possible to get things working - see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends what you mean by "center"

If you mean put it in the center of the pie chart, you can use [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.text`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html)

Example (replacing the `ax.set_title` line):

```
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'sample title', transform = ax.transAxes, va = 'center', ha = 'center', backgroundcolor = 'white')
```

Output:

[image]

You can play around with the parameters to `text` to get things like different background colors or font size, etc. You can also use `fig.transFigure` instead of `ax.transAxes` to plot in figure coordinates as opposed to axes coordinates.

If you want the title to be *centered* on the top of the figure, use [`fig.suptitle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.suptitle) instead of `ax.set_title`.

Output:

[image]

(Note that the `y` argument to `suptitle` is set to 0.85 in this one. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55767312/how-to-position-suptitle) about positioning `suptitle`.)

Comment: I wish (0.5,0.5) is the center of the graph, but actually it do not include the legend part. so it's still the center of the pie.

Comment: @lucky1928 see edits made to post