# How to change title space in matplotlib/seaborn plot - Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I have created a plot using matplotlib and seaborn in python. The code is given below:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8), facecolor='#e4e5e9', dpi=100,)
spec = fig.add_gridspec(ncols=6, nrows=2)

ax0 = fig.add_subplot(spec[0, :4])
sns.countplot(x='Min. Exp.',data=df, color='#657ffb', **{'edgecolor':'black'})
plt.ylabel("Job Count", fontsize=11)
plt.xlabel('Minimum Experience', fontsize=11)
plt.xlim(0,20)
plt.ylim(0,2400)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec[1, :4])
sns.countplot(x='Max. Exp.',data=df, color='#bad2ef', **{'edgecolor':'black'})
plt.ylabel("Job Count", fontsize=11)
plt.xlabel('Maximum Experience', fontsize=11)
plt.ylim(0,2400)
# plt.xlim(0,20)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(spec[:, 4])
sns.boxplot(y=df['Min. Exp.'], color='#657ffb')
plt.xlabel('Minimum Experience',labelpad=5, **{'fontsize':10})
plt.ylim(0,31)
plt.ylabel('')

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(spec[:, 5])
sns.boxplot(y=df['Max. Exp.'], color='#bad2ef')
plt.xlabel('Maximum Experience',labelpad=5, **{'fontsize':10})
plt.ylabel('')
plt.ylim(0,31)

for ax in [ax0,ax1,ax2,ax3]:
    ax.patch.set_alpha(0.0)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

fig.suptitle('Job Experience Demanded in  Data Scientist Roles in India', fontsize=17, y=1)
plt.savefig('job_exp2.jpg')
plt.show()
```

And the output is:
[job_exp2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRr6P.jpg)

But the title is **too close to the top edge**. (The y parameter in fig.suptitle() can only adjust space below the title). How can I adjust the title position slightly downwards or add some space above the title (so that it is not too close to the edge)?

Comment: See if this will resolve the issue - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55767312/how-to-position-suptitle)

Answer (score 0):

use `plt.savefig('job_exp2.jpg',bbox_inches='tight')`

or try using `plt.title('Title', x=0.5, y=0.9)` or whatever fits in your figure.

can also try `plt.title('Title', pad=value)`