# Changing the background color of plot on Jupyter using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter

I am using `jupyter notebook` for simple plotting tasks as the following.

```
%matplotlib inline

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12, 8)
plt.style.use("bmh")
```

I am getting a plot of the following form. How can remove the background silver color (we can keep the grid but I can also turn them off using `plt. grid(False)`) to white and change the border color of the plot to black?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"bmh"` style [sets the](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/a3825f4880c7a80fe51a74516c11aebbd2c764d3/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/bmh.mplstyle#L15) axes facecolor and edgecolor like

```
axes.facecolor: eeeeee
axes.edgecolor: bcbcbc
```

You can set them back after setting the style,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use("bmh")
plt.rcParams.update({"figure.figsize" : (12, 8),
                     "axes.facecolor" : "white",
                     "axes.edgecolor":  "black"})
```

Comment: Concerning your (now deleted) comment about the legends, I would reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864735/matplotlib-and-ipython-notebook-displaying-exactly-the-figure-that-will-be-save) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317)

Comment: I sorted it out and that's why I deleted it but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following way. The following answer is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088687/how-to-change-plot-background-color/23907866) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778954/elegantly-changing-the-color-of-a-plot-frame-in-matplotlib) posts

```
%matplotlib inline

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (8, 6)
plt.style.use("bmh")

plt.hist(np.random.normal(0,1, 10000), bins=100)
plt.gca().set_facecolor("white")
plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), color='k') # Change the frame border to black ('k')
```

An alternative way using `ax` object could be

```
%matplotlib inline

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (8, 6)
plt.style.use("bmh")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.hist(np.random.normal(0,1, 10000), bins=100);
ax.set_facecolor("white")
plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), color='k')
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. But how about without creating a new figure handler (` fig, ax = plt.subplots()`? Is there any way to set the border color to black with `plt`?