# How to conciliate dots annotation in Matplotlib scatter plot with manual limit setting?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm trying to conciliate dots annotation in a Matplotlib scatter plot with a manual limit setting, but I either got an error message or I get a design problem.

**Here is my code :**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,10)) #manual limit setting
plt.axis([-2,3,-2.5,5])
plt.scatter(x, y)


for i, txt in enumerate(n):   #dot annotation   
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]))
```

Here is a screen cap of the output (I got the final scatter plot as a small rectangle located in the left corner of a big white rectangle :

[image: Output]

**I tried this also :**

```
 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,10))
    ax = plt.axis([-2,3,-2.5,5])
    plt.scatter(x, y)


for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]))
```

But of course I got the following error message (even though the chart correctly displays, but without the labels next to each corresponding  dot).

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'annotate'
```

The error arises because my loop tries to iterate through `ax = plt.axis([-2,3,-2.5,5])`, which doesn't make sense indeed.

Any solution to overcome this issue ?

Thank you

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are you using? Does this problem still occur in matplotlib  3.1.2? (I think it's fixed by now, but if not, it would be good to know.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem occurs because of the special casing of texts when it comes to clipping. Usually you might want text outside the axes to be shown. Therefore annotations and text have a `annotation_clip` argument. However, this interferes with the `bbox_inches="tight"` option when saving annotations, because the annotations is then still considered part of the layout and hence the figure takes annotations outside the axes still into account.

Two solutions:

1. **Set `annotation_clip` *and* `clip_on`**. I.e. You may explicitely tell the annotation to clip at the axes:

   ```
   ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]), annotation_clip=True, clip_on=True)
   ```
2. **Set `bbox_inches` to `None`**. When using the IPython inline backend you can tell it not to expand the figure via

   ```
   %config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None}
   ```

   in a cell before starting to create your content. (This is seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37879281/4124317))

Comment: So the incorrect sizing in the question is caused by text being placed outside the axes? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @WilliamMiller Correct. Unfortunately they did not provide a [mcve], so one needs to interprete a little. To reproduce use e.g. `x = y = [-1,2,9]` and run the code in IPython or Jupyter notebook with the inline backend.

Comment: Interesting, thanks - one other question: do you know why the text doesn't show up in the image in the question? Why there is just blank space above and right of the axes?

Comment: @WilliamMiller Those texts are not drawn, but they are taken into account for the tightbbox calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate the first issue (tried in versions 2.2.3, 3.1.1, 3.1.2) - I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVlyh.png) (using random data). Try upgrading your version of matplotlib or using

```py
plt.savefig('/path/to/output/image.png')
```

To save the figure to the disk instead of showing it directly and see if the problem persists.

I can however explain the error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'annotate'
```

This occurs because `plt.axis()` returns `[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]`, not an `axes` instance (`fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10)` returns an `axes` instance to `ax`).

Comment: I have the latest version (3.1.2).

It still displays the graph in a weird design, but when I export it, it works ! Thanks

Comment: @alexnesov No problem, don’t forget to hit [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if this helped resolve the issue - that way the question is marked as such for future users

Comment: sorry, I forgot :)

Comment: @alexnesov No worries