# title in italic font in matplotlib isn't working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from textwrap import wrap

x_list = [11, 3, 6, 5]
label_list = ["red colour", "blue colour", "green colour", "back colour"]

title = "Some really really long long long title I really really need - and just can't - just can't - make it any - simply any - shorter - at all?"

newtitle = '\n'.join(wrap(title, width=50))  # wrap the long title so that it won't get cropped.

# here if I print `newtitle` first then "text below the main title" gets convert into italics
newtitle = "%s\n$%s$"%(newtitle, 'text\ below\ the\ main\ title') 
# but If I print `newtitle` after the secondary text it doesn't convert into italics
newtitle = "%s\n$%s$"%('text\ below\ the\ main\ title', newtitle)  # comment this line for 1st effect

plt.figure(figsize=(7,6), dpi=100)
plt.axis("equal")
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.8, top=0.7)
plt.rc("font", size=10)
explode = [0.03, 0, 0, 0]

plt.pie(x_list, labels=label_list, explode=explode, autopct="%1.1f%%", startangle=90)
plt.title(newtitle, size=12)

plt.savefig('test.png')
```

So my main problem is -

secondary text come first in normal font and then main title(`newtitle`) come after this  in italics/light font (looks pretty).

`newtitle = "%s\n$%s$"%('text\ below\ the\ main\ title', newtitle)`

Can we do it without using `$` sign?

Comment: have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4056853/832621 ?

Comment: @SaulloCastro: yeah.. but its too much code. I wonder if this can be done smartly/shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the intended result?

[image]

It can be done in a quick and dirty way using `mathtext`, but you have to have `$` flaking each lines, such as:

```
newtitle = '\n'.join(['$%s$'%item for item in wrap(title, width=50)]).replace(' ', '\ ')
newtitle = "%s\n%s"%('text\ below\ the\ main\ title', newtitle)
```

But I think a better looking way is to have these two titles separated. You can use `suptitle` for the upper one, or maybe just use `text`, either way you can then control their properties independently. e.g.:

```
plt.pie(x_list, labels=label_list, explode=explode, autopct="%1.1f%%", startangle=90)
plt.title('\n'.join(wrap(title, width=50)), size=12, style='italic')
plt.suptitle('some title', y=0.85, x=0.45) #y and x needed as you have adjusted the subplot size already.
```

[image]