# Anchor or lock text to a marker in Matplotlib

Tags: python, text, matplotlib, marker, annotate

Is there any way to **anchor or lock text** to a marker? When using the interactive zoom provided by `pyplot`, the text is moving out of bounds like shown in picture.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[2,4]
y=[2,3]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, 'ro',markersize=23)

offset = 1.0 
ax.set_xlim(min(x)-offset, max(x)+ offset)
ax.set_ylim(min(y)-offset, max(y)+ offset)

for x,y in zip(x,y):
     ax.annotate(str(y),  xy=(x-0.028,y-0.028))

plt.show()
```

[image: Text is out of bounds]

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that it is done by default. The text's lower-left corner is tied to the position specified with `xy`. Now, as you can see in the figures below, when you zoom interactively onto one of the markers, the relative position of the marker and text is preserved.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[2,4]
y=[2,3]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, 'ro',markersize=23)

offset = 1.0 
ax.set_xlim(min(x)-offset, max(x)+ offset)
ax.set_ylim(min(y)-offset, max(y)+ offset)

for x,y in zip(x,y):
     ax.annotate(str(y),  xy=(x,y))

plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

However, this looks rather ugly as the text is now in the upper right quadrant of your marker and sometimes even lies over the marker's edge. I suppose this is the reason why you have added an offset of 0.028 in `xy=(x-0.028,y-0.028)`, hence introducing the behavior you are now trying to get rid of. What happens is that by default `matplotlib` uses the data's coordinate system to position your text. When you zoom, the 0.028 data-units represents an increasing proportion of your frame and the text "drifts away" from your marker, eventually ending outside of the visible range of values.

To get rid of this behavior you need to change the coordinate system. The `annotate` argument `textcoords` can be set to `offset point`. Here `xytext` lets you specify an offset (in points) from the `xy` position:

```
ax.annotate(str(y),  xy=(x,y), xytext=(-5.0,-5.0), textcoords='offset points')
```

Now the challenging part will be to assess the size of the text that you want to add to your plot in order to determine the offset's value. Likely the text will change but there is no way to determine the size of the rendered text string before it is drawn. [See this post on that matter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018860/text-box-with-line-wrapping-in-matplotlib#4056853) In the example code below, I attempted to introduce a bit of flexibility:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[2,4]
y=[2,12]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, 'ro',markersize=23)

offset = 1.0 
ax.set_xlim(min(x)-offset, max(x)+ offset)
ax.set_ylim(min(y)-offset, max(y)+ offset)

for x,y in zip(x,y):
    text = str(y)
    fontsize, aspect_ratio = (12, 0.5) # needs to be adapted to font
    width = len(text) * aspect_ratio * fontsize 
    height = fontsize
    a = ax.annotate(text,  xy=(x,y), xytext=(-width/2.0,-height/2.0), textcoords='offset points')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Here, the text is a string of length 2 and it is still roughly centered on the marker despite a lot of zooming. Yet you will need to adapt this solution to your font and fontsize. Suggestions for improvements are much welcome.

Comment: I believe calculating width and height is not necessary as one can use `ha="center"` and `va="center"` to deal with horizontal and vertical alignments.