# Left and right alignment of paragraph text (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I have been looking for a way of making a a piece of text left and right aligned (i.e. "margin adjusted" or `ctrl-J` in OpenOffice for example) in a matplotlib text field, to form a nice column (delimited by the width of the `matplotlib.axis`-object).  I'm not sure if the proper term is "left and right aligned", but I would like it to be as in the example below:

Example of only left-alignment, i.e. not what I want:

```
This is some sample text withsomeverylongwords
that I would like to be wrapped. It should adjust 
to the left and right margin such that they are at
the same distance.
```

Example of what I would like:

```
This is some sample text withsomevery-
longwords that I would like to be wra-
pped. It should adjust to the left and 
right margin such that they are at the 
same distance.  It should not wrap the
final line.
```

The `matplotlib.text` has a kwarg `wrap=True` ([example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/text_labels_and_annotations/autowrap_demo.html)), but as far as I can see it only wraps to the figure width.  Further it only aligns either left, right or center but not both.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018860/text-box-with-line-wrapping-in-matplotlib) answer shows how to wrap to the targeted `axis` but without margin adjusted text.  It is using the [textwrap python module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) as a base.

What I would like is a function that wraps text, preferably directly in accordance to a matplotlib axis.  If it needs to cut long words it should do that with a dash. Latexed equations should not be broken, which [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018860/text-box-with-line-wrapping-in-matplotlib) already takes care of. If possible it should also adjust space sizes inside each line to make th edges straight, but I believe this might be much tougher (I imagine this can be done with some well-placed Latex `\hspace`'s inside the string).

Has this been done?  I have a hard time thinking it hasn't since every modern text editor such as MS Word and OO Write has it, but I can't find any example of such code for Python.  If it hasn't I would be greatful for ideas how to implement it.

Comment: I don't know the answer to Your question, but there is a way to insert Latex in matplot.lib text. Maybe that is the way to go. Take a look: http://matplotlib.org/users/usetex.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I am already aware that you can insert inline latex-equations for example. One solution I have in mind is to actually latex the entire text-field, but making it compile as I want it seem to be a nifty problem.

Comment: mpl contains a limited port of LaTeX to python (just the math rendering).  I full reimplementation of the LaTeX layout engine in python would be an interesting project, but probably out of scope for mpl.