# Wrap text in matplotlib table

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to create a table using matplotlib from a list of dictionaries.

For this I use the following function, which I found in another answer on this site:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.externals import six
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rc('font', family='Arial')

def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=3.0, row_height=2, font_size=10,
                     header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'w'], edge_color='w',
                     bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0,
                     ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
        ax.axis('off')

    mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)

    mpl_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    mpl_table.set_fontsize(font_size)

    for k, cell in six.iteritems(mpl_table._cells):
        cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
        if k[0] == 0 or k[1] < header_columns:
            cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w', wrap=True)
            cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
        else:
            cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[k[0]%len(row_colors) ])
    return ax
```

The problem is that I cannot wrap the text inside a cell, even though I put the properties at `cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w', wrap=True)`.

Example image:[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `wrap=True` wraps the text at the figure edges. It won't help here. I'm not aware of an automatic solution, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018860/text-box-with-line-wrapping-in-matplotlib?rq=1) may help you to  build one yourself.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for the tip. I will check it out.

Comment: is that worked for you? I am also facing same issue. please share the solution you picked, even alternative table solution instead of matplotlib but with table wrap. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Hello, @Haranadh: I ended up using Reportlab. It is much better for generating tables. Check it out here: https://www.reportlab.com/opensource  Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to apply an automatical wrap, an additional option might be the useage of `textwrap` at your table content outside the tables definition.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import textwrap as twp
import numpy as np

#create column headers with long text and apply textwrap with \n after defined lenght
columns=[twp.fill('this is a long column header text',25), twp.fill('...and this is an even longer column header text',25)]
#create rows
rows=[1,2]
#create (stupid) content
cell_text=[[100,200],[100,200]]

#create figure with simple data (just for demo)
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1)
x=np.arange(100)
ax.plot(x,np.sin(x/10))
# insert table with wrapped column headers and data
table=ax.table(cellText=cell_text,
                  rowLabels=rows,
                  colLabels=columns,
                  loc='bottom',
                  bbox=[0.0,-0.3,1,.2])

#adjust format of table and plot
table.auto_set_font_size(False)
table.set_fontsize(9)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.1)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: example of table with text wrap]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to just use '\n' in your text and then play with column width and row height.  It is not a built in feature.