# Text within a cell in matplotlib table

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-table

I am drawing text in a table in matplotlib.

When text is more than the cell width it is drawn outside the cell.

I would like the to wrap the text.

Is there a solution for that?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278040/wrap-text-in-matplotlib-table)

Comment: Looked already, but didnt help