# How to make a customized Text object interactive in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a customized `Text` object, which has the same logic as the following simplified object:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.text import Text

class MyText(Text):
    def __init__(self, x, y, txt, height, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(x, y, txt, **kwargs)
        self.height = height
        
    def mydraw(self, ax):
        txt = ax.add_artist(self)
        myset_fontsize(txt, self.height)
        return self
    
    def set_height(self, height):
        self.height = height
        #myset_fontsize(self, height)


def myset_fontsize(txtobj, height):
    trans = txtobj.get_transform()
    pixels, _ = trans.transform((txtobj.height, 0)) - trans.transform((0,0))
    dpi = txtobj.axes.get_figure().get_dpi()
    points = pixels / dpi * 72
    txtobj.set_fontsize(points)
           
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.grid(True)
    txt = MyText(0.2, 0.2, 'hello', 0.1)
    txt.mydraw(ax)
```

`MyText` is different from the built-in `Text` in that the fontsize is dependent on the `height`, which, for example, specifies the height of the text in the data coordinates. Except this, `MyText` is almost the same as `Text`. The example code gives the following figure:

[image]

This works fine for a static image. However, I want `MyTest` to be interactive, which includes the following goals:

- In an interactive plot mode, `txt.set_height(0.5)` shoule change the fontsize dynamically. I know I can add a snippet as the comment shows, but if `MyText` object is not added to the axes, `txt.set_height(0.5)` will throw an `AttributeError`. In short, `txt.set_height()` should behave similarly to `txt.set_fontsize()`.
- When the figure is resized by dragging the plot window, `MyText` should change the fontsize accordingly, that is, the height of text in the data coordinates should keep the same. But currently the fontsize is unchanged when resizing the figure. I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018860/text-box-with-line-wrapping-in-matplotlib), but `mpl_connect` needs some way to get the `Figure` object, and I want `MyText` interactive after calling `txt.mydraw(ax)`.

[image]

- When I change the aspect ratio of the figure, `MyText` should change the fontsize accordingly, same as the second point.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score -1):

After reading the [user guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/interactive_guide.html), I found that every artist has a `stale` attribite, which is some signal to re-render the figure. The complete solution is as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.text import Text

class MyText(Text):
    def __init__(self, x, y, txt, height, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(x, y, txt, **kwargs)
        self.height = height

    def __call__(self, event):
        # When calling myset_fontsize, `self.stale` will be `True` due to `self.set_fontsize()` in the function body.
        myset_fontsize(self, self.height)
        
    def mydraw(self, ax):
        txt = ax.add_artist(self)

        # Connect "draw_event" so that once a draw event happens, a new fontsize is calculated and mark the `Text` object is stale.
        ax.get_figure().canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', self)

        return txt
    
    def set_height(self, height):
        self.height = height
        # When a new height is set, then the
        #`Text` object is stale, which will 
        # forward the signal of re-rendering 
        # the figure to its parent.
        self.stale = True


def myset_fontsize(txtobj, height):
    trans = txtobj.get_transform()
    pixels, _ = trans.transform((txtobj.height, 0)) - trans.transform((0,0))
    dpi = txtobj.axes.get_figure().get_dpi()
    points = pixels / dpi * 72
    txtobj.set_fontsize(points)
```

This solution almost solves my problem although it's not perfect. It's a little inefficient.

Any improvements are appreciated.